# Using queue length of delayed job/resque in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, queue, delayed-job, resque

Is there a way to show or use the queue length of one of the gems `delayed job` or `resque` in one of my views in rails 3?

I'd like to implement something like `"you are number X in line, please wait"`

assume I have many many jobs (like sending a lot of emails) and the queue does not empty as soon as there is something in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure of delayed_job but you for resque can get the information about

the length of the message in resque queue provide you know the queue name

Here How

```
require "rubygems"
require "redis"
require 'redis/namespace'
redis = Redis.new
namespace ||= :resque

@redis = Redis::Namespace.new(namespace, :redis => redis)
puts @redis.llen "queue:[my queue name]"
```

`llen` is redis command to  et the length of a lists omething like `.length`  and `.count` for array in `ruby`

Hope this help